# upsampling for a signal

Tags: digital-communications, sampling

We have a signal $s(t)$.

1. If we do an upsampling, does the signal duration increase?
2. What is the point of upsampling if the signal time increases?
3. Can we do an upsampling if we don't use a shaping filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you upsample a signal, its duration (i.e. measured in real-world units like "seconds") does not change.

- If your signal $s[n]$ is sampled at a rate $f_s$ Hz, and it is $N$ samples long, then the total duration of the signal is $\frac{N}{f_s}$ seconds.
- Say you upsample the signal by a factor $M$, yielding a new signal $s_u[n]$. It will be $MN$ samples long, but it will be sampled at a new rate $Mf_s$. Its duration is therefore $\frac{MN}{Mf_s} = \frac{N}{f_s}$. You can see that the signal duration is the same as $s[n]$.

It's not clear what you mean by a "shaping filter" in your third question.

Comment: In the third question, 'shaping filter' is for example a root raised cosine filter: Can we do an upsampling if we don't use a shaping filter (for example a root raised cosine filter)?

Comment: upsampling has not necessarily something to do with pulse shaping, so yes.